# Accessing the pointers of a static function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I am new to C and C++. I have defined a static function which has a pointer 'ptr'. How can I access the pointer outside the function?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static void accessArr(uint8_t arr[]);

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

    accessArr(arr);
    
    cout << *ptr <<endl;
    return 0;
}

void accessArr(uint8_t arr[])
{
    uint8_t *ptr = arr;
}
```

I am getting the below error for the above code. Please help in solving the error.

```
main.cpp:12:14: error: ‘ptr’ was not declared in this scope

     cout << *ptr <<endl;
              ^~~
```

Comment: `cout << arr[0] <<endl;`? It's not clear why you want to use a variable that's local to another function.

Comment: Local variables inside functions are local variables no matter what. Their scope and life-time follows the same rules both for statis and non-staticfunctions.

Comment: @churill No, I want to print the first element of 'arr' array using pointer 'ptr'

Comment: You cannot do that because `ptr` is a local variable of `accessArr`. Workaround is calling some function from `accessArr`, passing a pointer or reference to `ptr`.

Comment: That's not how C++ works.  Function variables are always only accessible from inside the function.

Comment: is it not possible as the pointer is assigned in the static function?

Comment: @Beginner And _why_ do you want to do this? Just use `arr[0]`. You can't access local variable from other functions. Maybe we can find a solution if you tell us what exactly you want to achieve and why. I think you maybe are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @Beginner This is a very well asked question for a beginner. Just so you know, even if the function is static, extern or inline it doesn't change the problem you had. The solution you accepted will solve it no matter the linkage of the function.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot getting your point, thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  name `ptr` is not declared and visible in main. Just declare the function as returning a pointer like for example

```
static uint8_t * accessArr(uint8_t arr[])
{
    return arr;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
cout << *accessArr( arr ) <<endl;
```

Or

```
uint8_t *ptr = accessArr( arr );

cout << *ptr <<endl;
```

Comment: I think that's the most useless function I've ever seen, but it correctly solves the problem. +1

Comment: Even if it looks trivial, I think such answers are really needed for beginners, as many will fail to understand where to begin. You could even add a section about out parameters or globals, even if not recommended so that the beginners knows what's possible and what to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

arr refers to the adress of firts element? If you need the arr address just write &arr

Comment: I think I know what you're tying to get at, but `arr` refers to the whole array, not just the first element. `arr` will [decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay) to a pointer to the first element, but `arr` will be and remain the array.